# Function works when called in body unload, but not when called as part of another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So here's the scoop - I've got a page with an animated progress bar in it here:

http://bushidodesigns.net/consumer/webapp/funnel/receipts.htm

The script that animates the bar looks like this:

```
function run() {

var obj = document.getElementById('p1');

if (obj.getAttribute("data-value") < 100) {
  obj.setAttribute("data-value", parseInt(obj.getAttribute("data-value")) + 5);
  obj.setAttribute('aria-valuenow', obj.getAttribute("data-value"));
  obj.style.width = obj.getAttribute("data-value") + "%";
}
```

And I'm firing it on page load like so:

```
<body class="step" onLoad="run()">
```

That works fine. But what I'm trying to do is put the progress bar in an external file, and load it into the page when the user clicks a link like this:

```
$(document).on('click','#load-email',function() {
$("article").load("../loaders/email.htm");
run();
});
```

When I do that, the progress bar loads into the page, but it loads at 100%, doesn't animate, and throws this error - "TypeError: obj is null if (obj.getAttribute("data-value") < 100) {"

Here's a link:

http://bushidodesigns.net/consumer/webapp/funnel/email.htm

Click the "continue" button to see the issue.

Any idea what is causing this? I'm completely stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `run()` after `email.htm` loads.

```
$(document).on('click','#load-email',function() {
    $("article").load("../loaders/email.htm", {}, function() {
        run();
    });
});
```

Comment: Woo hoo! Thank you, I've been trying to figure that out for hours.